# Wrong date time format when insert date from PowerApps into Sharepoint list

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, powerapps, excel-dates

I have a Powerapps app to allow user to select a date with dd-mm-yyyy format and direct insert it into Sharepoint list with same format (no time). It works normal but some records from users could insert date with time in Sharepoint List. It shows only date in Sharepoint list but when I export list rows to Excel, some records are with time. It made some steps of Power automate fails when reading data from excel because it accept integer only if it contains time it will have decimal number and caused errors. Would you please advise what's wrong? Thanks a lot.

Joanne

[Date settings in PowerApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kscj.jpg)

[Data in Date columns in Sharepoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwOfi.jpg)

[Date columns setting in Sharepoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkara.jpg)

[Data in excel column export from Sharepoint List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCq4J.jpg)

Comment: How are you submitting the data from the PowerApp to your SP list? Is it a Patch() function or a SubmitForm()? Could you share the formula?

Comment: @JBerg, I submitted the form by "SubmitForm(EditForm1)"

Answer (score 0):

In Power Automate you can use expressions to remove the decimals.

```
substring(string(outputs('Compose')),0,indexOf(string(outputs('Compose')),'.'))
```

Replace `outputs('Compose')` with your date values. So this will turn 1023.45 into just 1023

Comment: Thanks JBerg, this is what I am doing as workaround. But I want to know the root cause to prevent further handling of the problem.

Comment: It looks like your settings are all configured correctly. Try this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/cannot-eliminate-time-from-date-and-time-field/m-p/2143263